# How do I connect Pex Line to Braided Hose?

Tags: plumbing, water, dishwasher, pex

I have a singular Pex type B hot water line running to my sink specifically for dishwasher hookup, however my dishwasher has a threaded hose line running from it to reach the sink. How/what do I do to connect the braided hose to a Pex line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a myriad of connectors that can be fitted to PEX piping. There are Sharkbite™ style connectors that simply push on to the pipe, there are clamp on fittings that require a crimping tool, there are tools to expand the PEX then the fitting is slipped into the expanded end which are held in place as the PEX returns to its original size. There are probably other methods that I'm not aware of.

You need to wander down to your local big-box store or local plumbing supplier and take a look at the options. Somewhere, you'll find a section of *adapters* - one of them will have a PEX connection on one end and threads on the other end. Take the threaded hose from the dishwasher with you and find an adapter that fits the threads on one end and uses your desired attachment method for the PEX side. Buy the adapter, go home happy.

By the way, since you have a threaded connection, you'll likely need some Teflon™ thread tape for that end. Run one wrap of tape around the male side of the threads (on your adapter), being sure to run the tape in the same (clockwise) direction that the braided hose will screw on (this prevents the threads from pulling the tape up and removing it as you screw them together). Then tighten the hose to the adapter.